# ObjID in Page Header

Tags: sql-server, metadata

I am reading this article: [Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a page](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/).

I have a database `MyDB`, and there is a table `MyTable` in the database.

I have the following questions:

1. If I do as follows:

   (1) use the following query to find the object ID for a table:

   ```
   Use MyDB;
   select sys.objects.name, sys.objects.object_id from sys.objects where (name = 'MyTable');
   ```

   (2) then use the following command to find all pages allocated to `MyTable`:

   ```
   dbcc ind(MyDB, 'MyTable', -1);
   ```

   (3) then in the result table, I choose one of the data pages (page type = 1), and use the following command:

   ```
   DBCC TRACEON(3604);
   DBCC PAGE (MyDB, 1, 17386, 3);
   ```

   Then in the dumped content (page header) of step (3), the  `m_objId` (`AllocUnitId.idObj`) field should equal to the object ID obtained in step (1). Is that correct?

   And whether that works for both user tables and system base tables, such as `sys.syscolpars` base table?

   Based on my test, the above two conclusion are both correct.
2. What is the meaning of Metadata: ObjectId? In [article](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/), the ‘metadata: objectId’ <> `m_objId`. But from my own tests, the ‘metadata: objectId’  always equals to `m_objId`. Why? The original article does not explain the metadata clearly.

I am using SQL Server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012 and 2014

Comment: If you don't get an answer to this it might be worth trying Paul Randal. I don't believe he frequents this forum but I know I've seen him on http://www.sqlservercentral.com, otherwise his details are available on his blog: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul. Just FYI, Paul's team wrote a lot of the internals of DBCC back in the 2005 days so he'll most likely have an answer.

Comment: Also, with question 1, yes you are correct.

Comment: There's a "Leave a Reply" form under the article, you could ask your question right there.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Paul mentions this about those "Metadata" fields in the blog post:

> Note that I didn’t include the fields starting with Metadata:. That’s because they’re not part of a page header. During SQL Server 2005 development I did some major work rewriting the guts of DBCC PAGE and to save everyone using it from having to do all the system table look-ups to determine what the actual object and index IDs are, I changed DBCC PAGE to do them internally and output the results.

So the "Metadata: ObjectId" field should always match the actual `object_id` from `sys.objects`.

The other part of the question was eventually answered in the linked blog post as follows:

> The `m_objId` is only the actual object ID for system tables with IDs less than 100, and for tables in databases upgraded from SQL Server 2000. For all other tables, the `m_objId` is part of the allocation unit ID.

So the `m_objId` will match for system tables (and upgrades from SQL Server 2000).  But for others, he says it's "part of the allocation unit ID."  That's a bit vague.

Running SQL Server 2017 here, I can create a user table with one index page and get the following for those two values from `DBCC PAGE`:

```
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 178
Metadata: ObjectId = 901578250
```

I can confirm that 901578250 matches what's in `sys.objects` `object_id` for this table.

So where does 178 come from?

Upon further research, Paul has another post: [Inside the Storage Engine: How are allocation unit IDs calculated?](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-how-are-allocation-unit-ids-calculated/)

In that, he discusses how the `allocation_unit_id` (from `sys.allocation_units`) is calculated from `m_objId` and another internal id field from the page headers (`m_indexId`).

So, essentially, after SQL Server 2000, the `m_objId` value is just a building block used to calculate the ID for the `allocation_unit`.  It's internal to the page and doesn't really map to something else (not in the same way that "Metadata: ObjectId" does anyway).